# including a directory in classpath of android ant build script

Tags: android, ant

I am new to ant stuff and

I have an android project which has a set of dependency jar files , 
like this

- C:\soundlibs\lib-sound1.jar
- C:\soundlibs\lib-sound2.jar
- C:\graphicslibs\lib-graphics.jar

When building the android project using ant I have to copy all the jars to android project's libs folder, otherwise it will fail to build

Is there a way to include the directories C:\soundlibs and C:\graphicslibs as part of the classpath so that when android script runs javac target it should find the relevant jars automatically , so that I do not have to copy them ??

Thanks ,

Comment: So you would like ant to copy a file? Why calling this "include"?. In general if you want to copy a file, use copy task. Details in the manual.

Comment: Is it possible to just tell ant to use a certain path as part of existing classpath of android build script ?

Comment: There are many possibilities, but your question is to general. Be more specific, post your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependencies are needed for the script to start at all, then you should add them to system classpath or using command line `-lib` switch. But this is usually not the case.

**Usually the jars are given to specific targets in the build file**: mainly `java` and `javac` targets. See [javac task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) for details.

If you write the script yourself, just specify all the jars in the `classpath` attribute. If you use a ready-made script, you must look into it and check where to put the jars or how to provide the local path. Sometimes it is complicated, as you would have to learn the sophisticated way of passing classpath to tasks.